# Can't narrow the type of an object property even after checking it with a type guard

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

TFlavour is a discriminatory union, which is then a value of an Object.

Trying to implement this, works in js, but ts gets angry.
[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgMQDYEMBuB7ArgJxgXhgAoBvGYGSmAOxRFxSQC4YQcsoAaCq2%20nRgGEMAWwgZqUaiBgsAzmwCW1AObAAvgEoYAH2JkelPg2YwAZozldDMFDhCKzigMaKho8ZOnylqjduBQSFg4AElnKEEcKBQRAhgAJShnDBwAEwAeBRxlFU54ZHRsHAA%20QJTqBRhwyOjYuRYwiKiYuMISG2EAaygaltiWDqphmjoTJgskK24RqjsHJ1d3MQkpEBYAcm6oDZt1GaoANRRqRSRUQZth4wFTNg4D2ZvlzzXN49PzlBgAUQAPNgoZwgXbDfY2ACyJxUGEusyMY1uLHu1nho34L1W3hgGyhqgwMAQ7EUIMCYI0gWAFSqLlqrQA0lAwHJ4gB5ABGACtkiAAHQ9ZlEPp1ERyTSBWn9ESM5m8sypH5AgAWRBgJKgbRKMCGVEcQuaIrkAG11SIALq855ITQ6yjUjBIKC8pAYFT6un1E0gDUWq3CFZeEDaAD0wdYLLkKGZMAARAAFHAYaD2MAwNIYKByagbGRQP6KBRyXm8mN7fyUvXC1pFvEwy2Ixg2mz2x3O13uqU16EYesYpD%2017SENhgDqqS6LKVUGiZaAA)

Expected:
ts to understand discriminated unions in loops,
as it understands it without loops

```js
type TFlavour = ({ 
    natural: true,
    naturalComponent : string
}) | ({ 
    natural: false,
    artificialComponent: string
}) 

type TIceCream = Record<string, TFlavour>

const IceCreams: TIceCream = {
    CokeIceCream: {
        natural:false,
        artificialComponent: 'Coke'
    },
    Vanilla: {
        natural: true,
        naturalComponent: 'Vanilla Extract'
    },
    Mango: {
        natural: true,
        naturalComponent: 'Mango Fruit'

    }
}


const iceCreamKeys = Object.keys(IceCreams)

iceCreamKeys.forEach( item => {
    if(IceCreams[item].natural){
    console.log(IceCreams[item].naturalComponent) // ts says "Property doesn't exists.."
    }
})


if(IceCreams.Mango.natural){
    console.log(IceCreams.Mango.naturalComponent) // Works here
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know how to do [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) on an object property like `IceCreams[item]` where you are indexing with a key whose type isn't known to be a specific [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  TypeScript is only following the *type* of the index, not the *identity*.  And the type of `item` is `string`.  If you have `item1` and `item2`, both of type `string`, then checking `IceCreams[item1]` wouldn't let you conclude anything about `IceCreams[item2]`, right?  And since TypeScript can't tell the difference between `item1` vs `item2` or `item` vs `item`, it can't narrow.  This is a known limitation of TypeScript reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  Maybe someday it will be addressed.  But for now, there's an easy workaround:

Just copy the value into a new variable, so that the problematic indexing occurs only once:

```
iceCreamKeys.forEach(item => {
    const x = IceCreams[item];
    if (x.natural) {
        console.log(x.naturalComponent)  // okay
    }
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKgMQDYEMBuB7ArgJxgXhgAoBvYGCmAOxRFxSQC4YQcsoAacymunBgMIYAthAxUoVEMwDOrAJZUA5sAC+AShgAfYmUrVa9JjABmDGZ24UUOEPJPyAxvMEixEqbIXK164KEhYOABJRygBHCgUYQIYACUoRwwcABMAHjkcRSUOeGR0bBwAPn8kqjkYUPDI6JlmELCIqJjCPUohAGsoKqbo5jb9Cl4jZjMkCy5Byhs7B2dXUXFJaRgAck6oVasYVUnKADUUKnkkVH7t-WH+Y1Z2Pamrhfdl5lXD49OUGABRAA9WFCOEBbfS7bYAWSOSgw5ymQ0M12Yt0scIMfCeS08a0hygwMAQbHkwP8oLU-mAZQqTmqzQA0lAwDJYgB5ABGACtEiAAHRdRlEHo1YQyPzAam9YT0xnckzJb6AgAWRCJUBaRRgAxglJAMF+sUFzRkAG0VcIALoAbm29mIv25jyQmk1+kpGCQUG5SAwSiIdodQkWHhAmm2ql85JtAsaQpk3Jx0PtCIYTu2rvdnu9UZptTjUIwifRSADzykmgA9GWYAB1ZIdJkKqCRMlAA)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly accessing the item with the index, try to store it in a separate variable. This way, TypeScript will recognize the right type:

```
iceCreamKeys.forEach( item => {
    const c = IceCreams[item]
    if(c.natural){
    console.log(c.naturalComponent) 
    }
})
```

(working [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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))

Answer (score -2):

```js
iceCreamKeys.forEach( item => {
    if(IceCreams.item.natural){
    console.log(IceCreams.item.naturalComponent) // Accessing it like this worked
    }
})
```

Just found out, this works too.

Comment: No, that doesn't do what you think it does.  `IceCreams.item` looks at the key named `"item"`, which is not `"CokeIceCream"` or `"Mango"`.  It "works" but is doing something different (and will probably actually have runtime errors )