# Typescript not infering object value

Tags: typescript

We have an enum in typescript that serves as a list of values. We then use this enum to create an optional key array.

In our function we are testing if the prop is populated and then testing if the object has the key of prop.

On the final return however, typescript is throwing an error `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.`, which is the guard we are doing in the second if.

```
enum PropTypes {
  typeOne = 'valueOne',
  typeTwo = 'valueTwo',
  typeThree = 'valueThree',
}

const mapObj: { [k in PropTypes]?: () => string } = {
  [PropTypes.typeTwo]: () => 'bere',
}

function test(str?: PropTypes) {
  if (!str) {
    return;
  }

  if (!mapObj[str]) {
    return;
  }

  return mapObj[str](); 
}
```

However if we change the function `test` to:

```
function test(str?: PropTypes) {
  if (!str) {
    return;
  }

  const fn = mapObj[str]

  if (!fn) {
    return true
  }

  return fn(); 
}
```

Then the error is gone.

Can anyone help me understand why typescript works in the second scenario? Is it because `mapObj[str]` refers to a different reference?

Comment: This is due to [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530); see the answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73666799/cant-narrow-the-type-of-an-object-property-even-after-checking-it-with-a-type-g) for more information.